# Background color issue with TIF file in XP

Tags: image, windows-7, background, windows-xp

I have an issue with a image file on XP and windows 7 but it works perfectly in windows 2008 box. Coming to the actual issue, the TIF image in the question is a Invoice form image with a white background with Invoice details. When I open it in 2008 it opens with white background but when I open it in XP and Windows 2008, it turns to black background with white color text. I am seeking some help on this issue.
1. Is it a OS issue 
2. if it is a OS issue, how do I change the background color to white using any code preferably C# as I am using C# for developemnt.

Thanks in advance

Satish

Comment: Could you  make one such file available unmodified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be a CMYK or transparency issue, or that it's saved in 16-bit color format (per component).

But this is hard to determine without access to one actual file for analysis.

Update:

Problem 1: For TIFF files - on Windows XP the Photometric tag is ignored by Windows Photo viewer and its underlying technology, with TIFF files using a single bitplane (2 colors). This is a bug.

Solution 1a: Manually enter (switching for existing) palette entries to force bit 0 (off) black and bit 1 (on) white.

Solution 1b: Save files as RGB files /gray-scale would be more ideal, but in GDI+ there is no good support for 8-bit gray-scale files IMO).

Problem 2: Byte-order. On Windows XP, the byte-order (big-endian) can cause problems. Normally TIFFs are saved in Motorola big-endian format (MSB) but on Windows XP the TIFF file is assumed to be in little-endian format.

Solution 2a: Save new TIFF files with little-endian order (Intel) for new files

Solution 2b: If Re-saving (re-scanning) is not an option for existing files, re-order content for existing files switching byte-order from LSF (Intel) to MSF (Motorola). Update header to indicate new byte-order (replace II for MM etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I noticed that it is an issue with images with 96 dpi only and other images with 200 and 300 dpi seems to have no such issue. File opens;
1. with white background and black fonts on Windows 2008, Windows 7
2. with black background and white fonts in XP

Please ignore the image behaviour in different OS in my original post, but what I mentioned here is actual. Kindly let me know as soon as possible.

Also, please let me know your email ID so that I send the image as I could not upload it here.

Regards,
Satish

Comment: Just use a file-sharing service, yousendit.com or something like that, and then paste the link in the comment field.

Comment: Here is the link from where image can be downloaded.
https://www.yousendit.com/download/WUJaZ296Y1M1bmdYRHNUQw
Thanks,
Satish

Comment: I didn't get any issues opening the file (XP sp3) in VS2010 using .net 4. The file is ok in regards to format too (RGB/8-bit per channel, 96 DPI). How/with what do you try to open the file?

Comment: A snapshot of the form I used to load the image: http://i50.tinypic.com/10cp8gy.jpg and the code: http://pastebin.com/ZbZ50uZ5

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. Let me give you the background of the scenario here. The code I have written is to basically convert 96 DPI images to 300 DPI and save it in a folder. DPI Conversion works fine but the background image is black as source image shows black background on XP system instead of white but it does show white on Windows 7 and 2008 box wich is expected behaviour. I really appreciate if you could suggest how to convert it to 300 DPI and store it physically on hardisk. However, I was curious to know   how it is shown on XP on your system using Paint or windows photo viewer.

Comment: Because for us it shows in an inverted color (Black background and white text) on all the XP system I tried. Wondering if it is to do with XP OS.

Comment: I tested again now and it shows correct in the photo-viewer. The XP I am using here is 32-bit. In my opinion there is no point in converting the DPI. Images are never measured in DPI, only pixels and DPI is an arbitrary value in that regards. Pixels will stay the same no matter what DPI is set. What version of .net do you use?

Comment: I am really Sorry, I sent you a wrong file. Please use this link. https://www.yousendit.com/download/WUJhRGx3YTJubHpsZThUQw Thanks in advance Satish

Comment: Ah, this file is in bitmap format (2 colors). That means there is only 2 bits used to determine if to draw background or foreground, on XP the guess for which color to use gets wrong. When you convert the file, make sure you use 24-bit RGB format instead of 1-bitplane (to avoid problems on XP). The files will be bigger, but they will work.

Comment: I also noticed an aspect ratio bug in the file, something that you could probably address too. I updated my answer, see if that doesn't help you out.

Comment: You guys rock. Your asnwer provided us lot of clues and we were able fix the image by swapping palette entries programatically. Another important clue is we can now ask people who scan images to create images in RGB format instead of bitmap format. Thank you very much again for your time - Satish

Comment: Glad to be able to help :) Why not tick the answer as correct (below the counter of the answer).

Comment: Definitely will do. One more clarification please. https://www.yousendit.com/download/WUJZWGJDTk1PSHlFQk1UQw This is the new file I have uploaded which does not have any such issues on XP and other OS. Could you please help me in understanding the difference between these two images? and how do I check whether it is bitmap or RGB format? When I checked pixelFormat property it shows same for both images. Please one last help. Thanks Satish

Comment: It has to do with byte order (big/little endian). You can open the file and read the 2 first bytes. If they are II (or hex 0x4949) then they are Intel (little endian). If MM (0x4D4D) then the file is Motorola (big-endian). The last file is in Intel format. Normally TIFF are in big-endian (Mac, Amiga). To avoid this always save in "Mac" (Motorola) format - to "repair" (it's not a bug, but not always supported), read bytes manually and swap byte order of the data.

Comment: Just to double confirm, 1st file that I sent which has issue on XP is in Motorola format and Second file (last file) which has no issue is in Intel format? As you are suggesting Motorola format I got little bit confused Sorry... please confirm once. Regards Satish

Comment: Sorry, I am confusing myself here (too much msb and lsb and I was re-downloading the wrong file :) comment deleted) It's the Motorola file (MSB) that creates problem. Answer updated.

Comment: Okay no problem. So you are confirming that the second file which works fine on XP is in Intel format and it has first two bytes as II where as file having an issue on XP has MM. Thanks for updating the answer and it is very clear. But your solution 2b is somewhat reverse of what mentioned here. Please confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Simply we can interchange the Palettes then Issue will be resolved by this...

```
         Dim plet As ColorPalette = Image.Palette
         plet.Entries(1) = c1
         plet.Entries(0) = c2
         Image.Palette = plet
```

But struck at identifying the Images that are having problem, i.e. because we have to apply this to the Images that are having Issues only. Otherwise correct images also inverted.